# How to pinpoint where a long function returns

Tags: c++, c, return

Suppose there is a function with 1000 code of line named LongFunction, and we used it:

```
bool bSuccess = LongFunction();
assert(bSuccess);
```

Here I got an assert when debugging, and I know there is something wrong with LongFunction, so I need to find where the function meet problems and returns:

1. I could probably debug it step by step, it works but is time-consuming, we don't what to do it this way.
2. I could search the keyword "return" (or even more refined search use RegExp), and set breakpoint at those returns, it should be faster, but it is still tedious manual work which can't be automated.
3. #define return TRACE(**LINE**); return

It works but have following problems:

- It will print too much redundant information as return is frequently used.(Or we could use some EnvVar to switch it on or off)
- Does't work for following case: if(bOK) return true;

Do you have any other creative ideas on how to pinpoint the problem?

**Edit:** 
Here are some details to let us focus on the problem.

1. It is about C++, and not platform specfic.
2. We don't want to refactoring the functions(Yea, I know we should), we even don't want to change any code - at this point we just want to provide some facility to make our application debugging easier. I also believe this should be a common requirement, don't you ever run into this?
3. The LongFunction() have multiple exit point, and the return type is not necessay bool(HRESULT, user defined errorcode...)

**Edit**: A summary of current discussions:
We have some controversies:

1. You should refactor the function.
   Yea, everyone know that we should, but that is not the point.If I had make the call to refactor the function, I won't be here to ask the question.
2. Find where the LongFunction() returns failure doesn't help.
   It is always the first thing I do to locate where the error occurs to know what happened, I am curious why this doesn't help, what did you do in this situation? (Assume I am already familiar with how the function works)

And we have 2 reasonable solutions:

1. ReturnMarker from Crashworks, a stack object in the function will destruct when function returns, set the breakpoint at the destructor will show you where it returns in debuger
2. CMyBool(x) from Binary & Sadsido, change the return type of LongFunction to CMyBool which can contruct from a bool, return from LongFunction will contruct that object, so just set a breakpoint at the constructor will work.

Comment: How does knowing where the function returns actually help?  The function may only have a single exit point with some local variable denoting "success" (as you have here) so I'm not sure what that buys you?  IMHO, you need to work out when the function actually fails and then debug it for that case.

Comment: I need to know how the LongFunction() failed, and it should be failed right before the function returns failure, knowing that place so that I could debug and analyze what the problem is, I think it should be a common requirement.

Comment: @Baiyan:  I think your assumption here is flawed.  If your function is 1000 lines long and it "returns" on line 800 this just tells you that something went wrong between line 1 and 800.  Only where the function is completely incohesive (spell?) could you definitely say that once you know the return point you'll know what the bug is.  One positive from this question/answer however, is you may have provided an argument in favour of SESE!

Comment: How do you know it failed right before it returned failure, if you don't even know exactly where it returns?  Just examining what's leftover data at the point of return is likely not useful.  You seem to want to apply mechanical solutions to the debugging of something you don't understand, and that approach is simply doomed.

Comment: The first thing I want to do in this situation is find out where it returns the failure, yea, it is possible I won't get to know how it failed immediately, but that is how I get the clue and trace into it, I am interested in how you deal with such situation?

Comment: I deal with the situation by getting in to what happens where things are going wrong.  You've got something wrong with a thousand line function, and you have no idea how that function works.  If you find a quick solution, you'll likely screw up something else, unless you do extensive testing (and I'd bet this function doesn't have unit tests either).  You will almost certainly need to understand this function, and refactoring it is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: "I deal with the situation by getting in to what happens where things are going wrong." Yea, that is why I need to look into the function to see what happened. Just let's assume I am quite clear about how the function works, that doesn't mean you don't need to look into where it fails and find out the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Obviously you ought to refactor this function, but in C++ you can use this simple expedient to deal with this in five minutes:

```
class ReturnMarker
{
   public:
   ReturnMarker()  {};
   ~ReturnMarker() 
   {
      dummy += 1; //<-- put your breakpoint here
   }
   static int dummy;
}

int ReturnMarker::dummy = 0;
```

and then instance a single ReturnMarker at the top of your function. When it returns, that instance will go out of scope, and you'll hit the destructor.

```
void LongFunction()
{
    ReturnMarker foo;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1, This is cooool, It just cause a minimum impact on existing code.

Comment: It's an application of the more general idea behind RAII.

Comment: Yea, It is used widely. I've thought about this before ask the question, but I only focus on whether I could print out the line num in destructor, didn't notice just set the breakpoint in destructor will work:)

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion (and I love RAII), but I'm not sure this will actually do what you want: You will hit the breakpoint on return, but the compiler will probably only emit a single call to the destructor and then JMP there after setting the return value. So, while you hit the breakpoint, you may still have no idea how you got there. This behaviour is likely to be compiler-dependent, so you may get lucky, but I wouldn't bet on it. Also, you'll hit the breakpoint if your function throws an exception, which may be useful to you as well.

Comment: Usually MSVC does preserve the call stack in this case, or at least it does in debug builds.  Making the dummy int static is important though -- if it were local or a class member, the compiler would notice that the variable gets thrown out anyway and probably just elide the destructor altogether.

Comment: @Crashworks - You'll get a call stack, but will the actual line with the appropriate 'return' statement be listed, or would it be a generic compiler-generated 'return-and-tidy' at the end of the function? @Baiyan - Did this actually work for you?

Comment: In MSVC debug builds I definitely get the correct return address. In release it's more of a crapshoot.  I don't know what gcc -g -O0 will do.

Comment: @Crashworks. I checked it myself using BCB2009, and on a small test case it works a treat!

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like it's time to refactor LongFunction()...

A 1000 line function is a bad code smell. Spend the time refactoring it into smaller, more maintainable functions. You'll find the bug(s) while you're at it, and it will be a worthwhile investment for the future.

Comment: A very good answer for the question "Should I refactor my 1000-line function?". But the question is "How to pinpoint where a 1000-line function returns?"...

Comment: @sadsido: That was the question, but it's not actually the *problem*... The problem is a chunk of code that's not behaving as expected, and seems to be not well structured/documented/instrumented/etc.

Comment: There's an old Irish joke. Guy is lost out deep farmland in the West of Ireland, he and stops at a farm and asks "How do I get to Galway", the farmer chews the cud for a minute and says "Going to Galway? Well Jaysus if I were you I wouldn't start from here". Roddy, you're answer is correct, but unfortunately unhelpful. The +1 I would give for correctness is negated by the -1 I'd give for unhelpfulness. Have a good one dude :)

Comment: @Roddy: Thanks for your suggestions, they are really best practices that we should follow, but we also should not expect the all code you are mantaining are so ideal, we have problems here and there, just say "We should..." won't solve the problems, we need to buy into the ROI and Timeline as well, that is the reality.

Comment: @binary, well, I wouldn't call it /that/ unhelpful ;-) The question as it stands is more like "I need to go from London to New York for a meeting - Which bus should I take?"

Comment: @Baiyan, I know all about those kind of commercial issues :-( but I feel you don't yet really understand the operation of the code in LongFunction(). And if that's the case, how can you realistically estimate how long it will take to fix a bug in it?

Comment: @Roddy: "Which bus should I take?" nice one :) +1 sure feckit why not?

Comment: If the questioner doesn't know the function well enough to know where it returns, no simple mechanical process will help in debugging.  It will almost certainly be necessary to understand the function, and refactoring it may well be the fastest way.

Comment: Even if you know how this 1000-line function works, but you can expect such long functions probally has multiple exit points, understanding the function won't help me to pinpoint the line where it returns, the question is all about how could I locate that line, as fast as possible.

Comment: @Baiyan, I'm at a loss to see how knowing which line the function is returning on is going to help you solve the problem. The 'return' itself isn't the error.

Answer (score 4):

Is this C or C++?

If C++, create a new class that wraps bool (say CMyBool), that has an automatic cast to bool.

Now have LongFunction return CMyBool (a quick search and replace will change all returns in LongFuntion to "return CMyBool(x)".

Now put a break point in the ctor for CMyBool, the debugger will now stop when CMyBool is created, which will be on the correct return statement in LongFunction.

The automatic cast to bool will stop CMyBool from breaking the code that uses CMyBool.

That will get you over the initial problem, but you larger problem is that LongFunction needs to be refactored.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why searching and replacing all return statements in LongFunction()? It is enough to have a CMyBool(bool) constructor and only change the return-value type for LongFunction, isn't it?

Comment: @SadSido: Yes, forgive me you are correct. It will try to convert the bool to CMyBool and use the ctor that takes a bool. I've been away from C++ for too long :)

Comment: @Binary: It is really a creative solution, and it works cool with Sadsido's improvement, but I am following concern: We need to change the existing code (although only the return type, but think about we need to support a large code base)
BTW, I really like the way to answer the question: give a solution, and point out we should refactoring the function if possible.

Comment: Baiyan: Then 1. Rename LongFunction to LongFunctionWorker. Create a new LongFunction that returns a bool and delegates all work to LongFunctionWorker. LongFunctionWorker returns CMyBool. Now the only file affected is the internals of the .cpp file containing LongFunction & LongFunctionWorker, nothing else is effected.

Answer (score 4):

If your problem is just plain laziness (nothing wrong with that btw), make sure that all return statements in LongFunction are of the form

```
return(value);
```

rather than

```
return value;
```

(for instance using a regex search-and-replace)

Then, use a slighlty modified preprocessor macro than your original suggestion:

```
#define return(value) { if (!value) TRACE(__LINE__); return(value); }
```

...or even

```
#define return(value) { assert(value); return(value); }
```

...or whatever you feel is appropriate

Comment: assert is not what we want as return failure at some point is legal. I am considering define the macro this way, but really don't want to change the existing code. as you know, has return(value) every well is really ugly.

Comment: @Baiyan: 1000 LOC for a function is very ugly. You need to weigh the time you are spending avoiding a solid solution against what a refactor would provide. If you are dead-set against a refactor then the only absolutely reliable way is to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define return { TRACE(LINE); return; }
```

That fixes your problem 4.

As far as the rest goes thats tjust the problem with coding.  This is why many systems return more complex errors (such as an HRESULT from a COM object) and/or spam something to the debug stream when a problem occurs.

A 1000 line function should be re-fectored though.  As you are seeing a long function proves incredibly hard to maintain.

Edit:  Would the following work better than the above?

```
#define return TRACE(LINE), return
```

Have had a few drinks so it may well not.

Comment: think about:
if(bOk) return true;
:(

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what platform your on.  Depending on the contents of `LongFunction` the following is how I'd approach this using gdb:

Let's imagine that your file 'f.cc' has the following lines:

```
1: bool LongFunction () {  /* ... */ }
2:
3: void bar ()
4: {
5:   bool bSuccess = LongFunction ();
6:   assert (bSuccess);
7: }
```

Here are the steps in gdb:

1. Add a breakpoint on the same line as the assert: `break f.cc:6`
2. Add a condition to that breakpoint for when bSuccess is false: `condition 1 (bSuccess==0)`
3. Run your program until that breakpoint is reached
4. Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function body: `break f.cc:4`
5. Jump back to that location (and it will stop at the breakpoint): `jump f.cc:4`
6. Debug the contents of LongFunction to see why it's failing.

The reason I say that it depends on the contents of LongFunction is that if LongFunction reads input from a stream, or modifies global variables etc then its behaviour the second time round may be different.  You should consider the above steps as being the same as if the code was:

```
3: void bar ()
4: {
5:   bool bSuccess = LongFunction ();
5:   bSuccess = LongFunction ();
6:   assert (bSuccess);
7: }
```

Comment: Richard, let us just assume the behavior won't change if you jump back (anyway,we could re-run the application if not), the keypoint is how should I know in which line in LongFunction() return the failure.

Comment: @Baiyan:  The above technique is helpful in situations where you have a function called successfully many many times, until one call fails.  Debugging from the program start may not be an option and this approach solves that.  How many returns does the function actually have?  An emacs/vi macro could be written where once you reached step 5 in the above - you'd run the macro (setting breakpoints at all return statements in LongFunction) and then you'd continue.  This would show you the exact point that the function exists.

Answer (score 0):

It visual studio I would place a breakpoint on the assert, then using the stack trace window click the next row up and that'll take you into the exit point of the method.

Comment: Really??? what does "click next row up " means? I remembered we should not see the internal calling of LongFunction in the callstack as you are already out of it.

Comment: In the stack trace window you should see all the previous calls in the stack - your current call (the assert) should be highlighted, and should have several rows above or below it. You can double click any one of these rows and go to that place in the stack. It's good because you can see all the values as they were at that place on the stack, too, which can be very useful

Comment: I've done this in c# and vb.net btw - I don't know if the same functionality exists in c++ etc. but I would have though it would.

Answer (score 0):

"I could probably debug it step by step, it works but is time-consuming, we don't what to do it this way."

How else do you debug?

I used to debug by:

1) finding a set of parameters that reproduce the problem.

2) step through the code with that set of parameters.

If there are a 1000 lines of code then how are you going to "refactor" without knowing EXACTLY what the function does and is supposed to do.

And how are you going to do this without stepping through the function. I thought that was what an IDE with a good debugger was for.

Quite frankly, I find the question almost humorous in a very sad way.

Comment: -1，I don't think you read the question cafefully, not to mention the comments. I don't want to refactor, I just want to find where cause the function fails in the LongFunction(), is that not you guys do in this situation???

Comment: I very much read the question and fail to understand how one can avoid doing 1 and 2 if one is actually going to be make a conscientious effort to debug the problem. Debugging problems in bad legacy code is as you say "tedious" and has much "manual work which can't be automated".

Comment: 1. I am reproducing the problem 
2. I am pretty clear about how the LongFunction() works. But the LongFunction() is too long and have multiple exit point, I want to pinpoint where it fails, that is the question.

Answer (score 0):

In 1982, I was tasked with fixing a broken flowchart program.  The program, written in machine-dependent Harris FORTRAN (I do not now recall whether it was in FORTRAN IV or FORTRAN 77), consisted of an 1100-line main program, a 900-line subroutine, and about a dozen subroutines that were each 10 to 20 lines long.

Oh, and there was almost no whitespace (blank lines) in the program, and the comments were not useful at all.

It took me 160 hours - four weeks, FULL TIME, with NOTHING else on my desk - to grok that code sufficiently to make proper repairs.

You are in a similar situation.  It is going to take a real investment of CPU time on your part for you to grok that 1000-line creature, well enough to have a handle on what all might go wrong, and what to do to fix it.

Finding the returns is easy enough.  For Microsoft AbysmalC++: Search for every instance of "return" and preface it with
"printf("\n\n--->>> punching out at line %d\n\n", __LINE__);"
 (or the equivalent on your system).  Obviously, you can't just do this automatically; you'll have to look at the local bracketing.  Then run your test and see where it tells you to look.

The fact of the matter is this: In the real world of computing, there are almost no real routines out there that actually need to be 1000 lines long.  In nearly 40 years in this racket, as student and professional, I have encountered exactly one routine that NEEDED to be longer than one printer page (about 60 lines) long, and that one was a very special case.  It was about three pages, all told.

On the other hand, I've seen a LOT of run-on modules, where the guy who wrote it was too lazy, or too incompetent, to factor it properly, and the maintenance programmers were too lazy, too incompetent, or too scared of their manager to go back and refactor it.

Finally:  Consider that this is probably not going to be the last time someone has to work on this module, and it may well not be the last time YOU have to work on it.  These kinds of things tend to be tar babies: once you touch them, you never get unstuck from them.  It might very well be worth your time to refactor at least, and quite possibly redesign/rewrite it FROM SCRATCH and first principles.