# I have a function with a lot of return points. Is there any way that I can make gdb show me which one is returning?

Tags: c, gdb

I have a function with an absurd number of return points, and I don't want to caveman each one, and I don't want to next through the function. Is there any way I can do something like finish, except have it stop on the return statement?

Comment: I don't know if you're asking more than "set a breakpoint on the return lines and run gdb until next breakpoint"

Comment: that's pretty much what I want, I'm just not sure how to do it short of setting a breakpoint on each one manually.

Comment: Though I am normally a defender of multiple return points, enough to describe as "absurd" seems to suggest that some refactoring might be in order...

Comment: The gdb in obj-c has a 'back' command, that does a backtrace.  Is it possible that this works if you call it after your function has returned?

Comment: @Kevin: backtrace after the function's returned will give you the call stack at that point, with no sign of the function in question.

Comment: @Nathon - just throwing stuff out there -- that's why it's a comment, surround with question marks :)

Comment: I agree with dmckee.  If your function is too painful to step through line by line, your function is probably too big.

Comment: It seems like the function's size isn't up to Alex. Otherwise, why would he call it absurd and blame it on Linus?

Comment: @Brian: Alex' reply suggests that he may be looking at some hairy internal of linux or something equally arcane, and every rules comes with it's exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pinpoint where a long function returns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311166/how-to-pinpoint-where-a-long-function-returns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [reverse debugging](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord/Tutorial) to find out where function actually returns. Finish executing current frame, do **reverse-step** and then you should stop at just returned statement.

```
(gdb) fin
(gdb) reverse-step
```

There is already [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649468/setting-breakpoint-in-gdb-where-the-function-returns)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're stuck setting breakpoints. I'd write a script to generate the list of breakpoint commands to run and paste them into gdb.

Sample script (in Python):

```
lines = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
break_lines = [line_num for line_num, line in enumerate(lines) if 'return' in line and
line_num > first and line_num <= last]
break_cmds = ['b %s:%d' % (filename, line_num) for line_num in break_lines]
print '\n'.join(break_cmds)
```

Set `filename` to the name of the file with the absurd function, `first` to the first line of the function (this is a quick script, not a C parser) and `last` to the number of the last line of the function. The output ought to be suitable for pasting into gdb.

Comment: How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Alex: Added a (quick and dirty) example.

Comment: Code generation is your friend. Even when the code to be generated is a gdb script.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a stretch, but the `catch` command can stop on many kinds of things (like forking, exiting, receiving a signal).  You may be able to use `catch catch` (which breaks for exceptions) to do what you want in C++ if you wrap the function in `try/finally`.  For that matter, if you break on a line inside the `finally` you can probably single-step through the return after that (although how much that will tell you about where it came from is highly dependent on optimization:  common return cases are often folded by gcc).

Comment: I know, but his function will probably trivially recompile as C++ if this will work for him.

Answer (score 0):

How about taking this opportunity to break up what seems to be clearly a too-large function?

Answer (score 0):

[This question's come up before on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311166/how-to-pinpoint-where-a-long-function-returns/1314452). My answer from there:

Obviously you ought to refactor this function, but in C++ you can use this simple expedient to deal with this in five minutes:

```
class ReturnMarker
{
   public:
   ReturnMarker()  {};
   ~ReturnMarker() 
   {
      dummy += 1; //<-- put your breakpoint here
   }
   static int dummy;
}

int ReturnMarker::dummy = 0;
```

and then instance a single ReturnMarker at the top of your function. When it returns, that instance will go out of scope, and you'll hit the destructor.

```
void LongFunction()
{
    ReturnMarker foo;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: It's a good answer, and I voted for the other instance. But this question specifies c, not c++.

Comment: Fair point. I echo Ben Jackson in that almost any C function can trivially recompile as C++ for the sake of testing, but that assumes a C++ compiler is available.